# One part of my c# coding of adding items to a database is not working. What can be the reason?

Tags: c#, sql-server

There are  text boxes in my windows form called txtName,txtAdd,txtTel & txtEmail. I need to add the text in this text boxes to my database table. My table name is "Table". I used the following code to add those text to my table. The table columns are Name,Address,Tel No. & email.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            String name = txtName.Text;
            String add = txtAdd.Text;
            String tel = txtTel.Text;
            String email = txtEmail.Text;

            String SqlQuery = "insert into Table values('" + name + "','" + add + "','" + tel + "','" + email + "')";
            SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
            con.Open();
            cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured while saving", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

I typed some texts and pressed button1. But everytime I get the "Error occured while saving" message box. I can't understand the reason for that. I used varchar data type for all of the fields in my table. I am using visual studio 2012 express. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This catch is useless. Change it to _catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);}_ and tell us what you get

Comment: @Steve, your comment should be the answer.

Comment: It appears that your sql is wrong. Also, you do not want to string concat text fields into your query due to sql injection. Look into SqlParameters.

Comment: maybe you typed `";GO DROP Table;GO"` in to one of the text boxes?

Comment: I suspect that there is a problem with that INSERT INTO without columns' names

Comment: @steve, then there is a red line under the message

Comment: @Steve its impossible to know without knowing the schema of Table.

Comment: @Jodrell, I didn't understand what you say

Comment: okay, I'll try and be helpful. An exception is being thrown, we need to know what it is. Change `catch` to `catch(Exception ex)` then we will get the exception is the catch block. Change `"Error occured while saving"` to `ex.Message`, then we will see what the exception is.

Comment: Or just let crash the code removing the catch block and let the exception show itself

Comment: very likely, you have the wrong number or type of values or they are in the wrong order.

Comment: Should I type that as MessageBox.Show(ex."Error occurred while saving")? Then there is a red line under the part within " ".

Comment: no `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)`, `Message` is a property of an `Exception`.

Comment: Same with that also. So I typed as ("error occurred while saving" + ex). Then there is a very big message box with a message like "Incorrect syntax near the 'Table'" and so on

Comment: edit the question and include all that text

Comment: I am guessing you don't have a table called `Table` or more likely the very fact it is called "Table" and not escaped is causing the problem. If this were MySQL I could tell you the delimiters, but it appears that is not actually the case.

Comment: change `Table` to `\`Table\`` if you are using mysql, `[Table]` for Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by your string concatenation of values to form an sql command. This is well known as a source of bugs and in a potential security risk called [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). Otherwise you could receive an error when using an INSERT INTO table without specifying the column names. If you don't write the columns then you should pass a value for every column of your table and in the exact order expected by your table.

You should use a parameterized query

```
public string conString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
 AttachDbFilename=c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Database1.mdf;
 Integrated Security=True";


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String name = txtName.Text;
        String add = txtAdd.Text;
        String tel = txtTel.Text;
        String email = txtEmail.Text;
        String SqlQuery = @"insert into [Table] 
                            values(@name,@add,@tel,@mail)";

        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        using(SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con))
        {
             con.Open();
             cmnd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
             cmnd.Parameters.Add("@add", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = add;
             cmnd.Parameters.Add("@tel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tel;
             cmnd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email;
             cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
     }
}
```

Notice also that I have moved your disposable objects inside a using block to ensure proper disposing of the objects SqlConnection and SqlCommand

**EDIT**  If you really have a table in your database named `Table` then you need to put square brackets around that name because it is a reserved word in Sql Server (or better, change that name to something more meaningful in relation to the data stored there)

Comment: As you know, fixing the vulnerability, while desirable, won't actually fix the schema mismatch.

Comment: @user6333477 change your code to this and see what happens

Comment: I know but the OP needs a reference code to start with

Comment: There is a red line under conString

Comment: Check the ErrorList window and report/fix your syntax error

Comment: When the program is running there is a error message like "incorrect syntax near the table"

Comment: Did you put the name of the table between square brackets?

Comment: Well, good to know, but I repeat myself, you shouldn't name your table in that way. It is a lot confusing and a source of time wasting problems.

Comment: Ok. But the software doesn't let me to change the table name it is there as table. How to change the name? I don't know

Comment: Well this is an administrative task, not something you do from code. Usually Sql Server comes with its administrative tool called Sql Server Management Studio. Here you have a lot of options to change the table name. Using right click and rename, using SQL system stored procedure sp_rename.

Comment: Steve I need to delete some items from my table according to the email. What should I do now?

Comment: Can I do this with this conString method?

Comment: Please post a new question with the relative details. It is not a welcome practice on SO to add new problems to an old question. You can always add a link in your new question to this one if there is something that need to be explained